# Is there a keyboard shortcut for returning to last scrolled position in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Often I find myself scrolling through my code and wanting to return to my previous position before I last scrolled.

I'd like to return to *the previous specific position/scroll location within the code I'm currently working on*, not just the previous .m or .h.

Is there a way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. It's Ctrl + Cmd + Left/Right Arrow.

Comment: that is just the keyboard shortcut for the forward and back buttons on the navigation bar (goes to previous and next file). that is exactly what you specified you _didn't_ want in your question.

Comment: Yeah but on second thought, back button **does** return me to portion of code I was previously scrolled to _within a particular .m or .h_. So perhaps I'll rephrase my question to clean this up.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not; I'm not even sure how you imagine this would work.

as an alternative you can use the navigation bar at the top of the code view to jump between method definitions.

the navigation bar will also recognizes "tags" such as `TODO`, `FIXME`, as well as `#pragma mark` definitions.

Comment: see my answer, I actually found a way thanks to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134200/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-cycling-through-pragma-marks-or-methods-in-xcod#comment30045984_20134332