# Is there a keyboard shortcut for cycling through pragma marks or methods in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Often I want to quickly switch my focus back-and-forth between different methods in my code.

Is there is a keyboard shortcut to do so?

Is there anything I can do to more quickly get-to/switch-between pragma marks?

Comment: I just open two window/assistant editor side-by-side

Comment: It's not between pragma marks but you can use Cmd + Shift + O for quick search for methods. Or you can do Ctrl + 6 and type the pragma mark or method name and hit enter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Ctrl + 6` this gives focus to the Document Items list. You can then type the method name partially (it even smartly handles typos), then press down and enter, you can also type `pragma marks` here.

`Cmd + Shift + O` for a global quick open of methods and files.

Comment: amazing, thanks. Any chance there's a shortcut for returning to the last place I was? So that if I switch over to a method I can be quickly transported back to the last one I was working on, or the last place I was scrolled to?

Comment: Ctrl + Cmd + Left/Right Arrow

Comment: @darkheartfelt if you have a touchpad, you could also two-finger swipe left/right to navigate through visited locations.